# Creating an array from condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

i need to create an array, but the object type is different depending on a condition, something like this:

```
  myList = condition()
      ? Array < { secondLabel: String, value: String } > []
      : Array < { label: String, value: Number } > []
```

but, Im getting these errors:

```
Cannot compare class Array [1] to object literal [2].

Cannot compare boolean [1] to empty array literal [2].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the array constructor !

```
const myList = true ?
  new Array<{ secondLabel: String, value: String }>()
  : new Array<{ label: String, value: Number }>()
```

or you can asert the type :

```
const myList = condition()
  ? [] as Array<{ secondLabel: String, value: String }>
  : [] as Array<{ label: String, value: Number }>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=50#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwDIEtowLwygJwK4CmMA-AFAwxgEDuMAgjjgIYIA8A3jBAaGACZImAIwIAbAFwwAyrhRgA5gBoYANyajCkmTjnyYAXwB8ACgCU5GJKq0GzNp1HCxW2QuVqNBSQDk8cETgGJqZAA)